# Assigning a Permanent, Static IP Address

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

I'm having difficulty assigning a permanent, static IP address to the default `eth0` interface on a system running Ubuntu 14.04.5 with the system ultimately resorting to no IP address.

As a precursor to the following, the target system is an embedded system and we cannot allow any network interface changes during the operation of the system.

My set up is as follows:

`network-manager` has been disabled.

`/etc/network/interfaces` has been configured as follows:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.200.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

There has been an issue during boot whereby the NTP server daemon can cause the system to hang for a good 5 minutes. Doing some Googling has indicated that a package called `ntpdate` goes a bit rogue - so this has been removed (we have our own method for setting the date/time of the system).

The `avahi-autoip` service has been disable to prevent an automatic private IP being assigned.

Fundamentally though, something is happening at some point later which is removing the static IP address bound to `eth0` - whether it is a lingering DHCP service (surely the `iface eth0 inet static` should prevent this) or something else running which I'm unaware of.

One thing I have noticed is that at some point in time, a `PING` is done to the DNS server on the internal network (IP 192.168.0.5, this DNS server is not accessible due to a differing subnet) which instigates some kind of package update check which fails - after the failure, a constant stream of `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unavailable` messages appear with no viable way of getting rid of them.

For reference, here are some outputs:

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:2d:2c:6f:5b
          inet addr:192.168.200.1  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:13544 (13.5 KB)  TX bytes:7311 (7.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:112131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:11558635 (11.5 MB)  TX bytes:11558635 (11.5 MB)
```

**ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 92:23:f9:47:e0:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:2d:2c:6f:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.1/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ip6tnl0: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
5: rmnetctl: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:6f:db:90:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**dhclient**

```
root      1301  0.0  0.1   3980  2728 ?        S    00:00   0:00 dhclient eth0
root      3198  0.0  0.1   3980  2728 ?        S    00:02   0:00 dhclient eth0
```

**PING error**

```
PING 192.168.0.5 (192.168.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.0.5 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

ii  librsync1:armhf                                       0.9.7-10                                            armhf        rsync remote-delta algorithm library
ii  rsync                                                 3.1.0-2ubuntu0.2                                    armhf        fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
rsync is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
netcat-openbsd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

**ifconfig after PING**
(note, no IP address)

```
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
g
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:2d:2c:6f:5b
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:16588 (16.5 KB)  TX bytes:23129 (23.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1425523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1425523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:214682465 (214.6 MB)  TX bytes:214682465 (214.6 MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what it seems was happening is that initially, when the system was configured, it was connected to a network with a DHCP server visible. The IP address of the lease obtained from the DHCP server is stored in a `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` file.

The static IP address that was given to `eth0` via the `/etc/network/interfaces` file gets withdrawn when the `dhclient` (and related services like `avahi-autoip`) subsequently gets withdrawn after about 5 minutes when the DHCP client times out.

The system attempts to allocate the address from the previous lease however, because it cannot negotiate with a DHCP server, this address is also withdrawn and the adapter `eth0` ends up with an auto private IP address. This APIPA address is allocated by the `avahi-autoip` service - which, if stopped, prevents a private address from being assigned.

There are a couple of temporary solutions to this:

1. Delete the `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` file
2. Stop the `dhclient` service altogether using `pkill`
3. Remove the `dhclient` package altogether

In our case, option 3 was the best method.

Also, whatever is causing the `PING` to execute and ultimately fail with the `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unavailable` still continues to occur. Although it clogs up the debug terminal output, its not too much of a problem.